# Find students from guardian email address using google-classroom api?

Tags: google-api, google-classroom

Is it possible to find all students for a given guardian email address using google classroom api?  Must the user making the request be an admin, or is it possible to create a g-suite user with less permissions could do this?

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43463046/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this via a single API call, but you can construct a script that will achieve the same thing. However, the script will need to run as a domain admin, as only admins have access to guardian email addresses. The way you would need to do this is:

- Get all of the students from the domain (you would need to do this using the Directory API, or you could first list all courses, then get all students from each course and build a list of all students)
- For each student, get the guardian info including the email address
- Build a database or lookup structure (e.g. dictionary/hashtable) of these two (student email vs guardian email), remembering that a guardian's email may have multiple students associated with it.
- Look up the DB/table with the guardian's email to retrieve the student email(s).

Depending on which language/framework you're using, and how often you need to do this will determine which approach you'd use.